# Active directory - query groups by email address

Tags: active-directory, query

How do I query my workplace's directory to get a list of all the groups with an associated email address that terminates in "fr"? I can use either the AD snap-in or the commandline tools, but no third party clients.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this custom LDAP query in the AD snap-in:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(mail=*fr))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I wish I had time to study LDAP :( Thanks!